# Jython to import "identically named" Java files residing in different directories

Tags: python, error-handling, jython

I am to use Jython to import two supposedly identical java files for comparison. The comparison is made on the basis of returned values, signatures, and constructors (This works fine, though the problem is in the import). One file resides in the `submission` folder and the other in the `solution` folder. The problem is the following,

When I run the following code,

```
    sys.path.append('Solution/')
    import GeometricShape
    sys.path.pop()

    sys.path.append('Submission/')
    import GeometricShape    <---- the imported module is the same as the one above
    sys.path.pop()
```

the second imported GeometricShape is of the one in the `solution` folder, whereas it should be of the `submission` folder. Deleting the module by `del(sys.modules["GeometricShape"])` would still keep the first `GeometricShape` in memory somehow. `imp.load_source` doesn't work because it is not a python source file. Creating `__init__` in the directories and importing the modules as `from Solution import GeometricShapes` doesn't work, for I get the error below,

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Solution/GeometricShape (wrong name: GeometricShape)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.SyspathJavaLoader.findClass(SyspathJavaLoader.java:123)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.python.core.Py.loadAndInitClass(Py.java:909)
    at org.python.core.Py.findClassInternal(Py.java:844)
    at org.python.core.Py.findClassEx(Py.java:895)
    at org.python.core.packagecache.SysPackageManager.findClass(SysPackageManager.java:133)
    at org.python.core.packagecache.PackageManager.findClass(PackageManager.java:28)
    at org.python.core.packagecache.SysPackageManager.findClass(SysPackageManager.java:122)
    at org.python.core.PyJavaPackage.__findattr_ex__(PyJavaPackage.java:137)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__findattr__(PyObject.java:863)
    at org.python.core.packagecache.PackageManager.lookupName(PackageManager.java:136)
    at org.python.core.PyModule.impAttr(PyModule.java:106)
    at org.python.core.imp.import_next(imp.java:720)
    at org.python.core.imp.ensureFromList(imp.java:888)
    at org.python.core.imp.ensureFromList(imp.java:856)
    at org.python.core.imp.import_module_level(imp.java:850)
    at org.python.core.imp.importName(imp.java:917)
    at org.python.core.ImportFunction.__call__(__builtin__.java:1220)
    at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:357)
    at org.python.core.__builtin__.__import__(__builtin__.java:1173)
    at org.python.core.imp.importFromAs(imp.java:1011)
    at org.python.core.imp.importFrom(imp.java:987)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx2.get_solution$4(D:\Grader\autograder.py:48)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx2.call_function(D:\Grader\autograder.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
    at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:120)
    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:307)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx2.main$9(D:\Grader\autograder.py:158)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx2.call_function(D:\Grader\autograder.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
    at org.python.core.PyBaseCode.call(PyBaseCode.java:120)
    at org.python.core.PyFunction.__call__(PyFunction.java:307)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx2.f$0(D:\Grader\autograder.py:159)
    at org.python.pycode._pyx2.call_function(D:\Grader\autograder.py)
    at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
    at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
    at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1275)
    at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.execfile(PythonInterpreter.java:235)
    at org.python.util.jython.run(jython.java:247)
    at org.python.util.jython.main(jython.java:129)
```

Is there a solution to this?

Thanks...

Comment: Are you comparing source files or compiled byte-code files? Regardless, why are you using "import" rather than opening the files with text or binary I/O, as necessary, to compare the contents of the files?

Comment: So I could invoke their Java methods using Jython.

Comment: Hmmm... Two "identical" classes loaded into a single run-time... I believe that is a problem in itself. However, why invoke the methods when the goal is to verify the files are the same? Are you tasked with ensuring that two different implementations of a class are functionally the same? If so, that is really a case for unit testing.

Comment: Thanks, how would Jython unit testing overcome this?

Comment: These are Java classes, not Jython source files, correct? The best choices for testing whether the files produce functionally equivalent classes would be to use [JUnit](http://junit.org/) or [TestNG](http://testng.org). However, if Jython must be used to do the testing, write one Jython file which has test code to call all contructers and methods and tests the results. Then, import one file, run the tests. Then import the other and run the tests again. So long as both classes pass the same tests, they are "equivalent" to the extent your tests have covered the possibilities, but not completely.

Comment: By "but not completely," I simply mean that unit tests alone cannot guarantee complete equivalence for non-trivial classes. It is rare that all possible boundary conditions, much less all possible combinations of inputs and outputs are ever tested. [Formal verification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_verification) or [program derivation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_derivation) are more reliable for assuring correct algorithm or general software performance, but they are rarely used outside of proving specific algorithms.